# smarty: prints $[object Object] - $[object Object] instead of value

Tags: php, smarty

I am giving a value in hidden input field

```
<input type='hidden' name='amount_{$smarty.foreach.product.index+1}' id="amount" value='{$product[0].price}'>
```

The above code prints

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" id="amount" value="$[Object] - $[object Object]">
```

but if I print `{$product[0].price}` this value separately( not in input field) it prints the correct value

Update:

I am setting values here, product id name and quantity to a cookie, I think the problem is in the else part because the problem occurs only for the first item.. also I am getting the price from database.

```
function addtocart($product_id, $quantity){
        $results = $this->db->rawQuery("select * from products where id=?", [$product_id]);
        $id = $results[0]['id'];
        $name = $results[0]['name'];
        if(isset($_COOKIE['products'])){
            $products = $_COOKIE['products'];
            $products = json_decode($products,true);
            foreach($products as &$product){
                if($product['id'] == $product_id){
                    $product['quantity'] += $quantity;
                    setcookie('products',json_encode($products),strtotime( '+30 days' ));
                    echo 'done';
                    return;
                }
            }
            $item = ['id' => $id,'name' => $name,'quantity' => $quantity];
            $products[] = $item;
            print_r($products);
            setcookie('products',json_encode($products),strtotime( '+30 days' ));
            echo 'done';
        }else{
            //echo 'else';die();
            $products = array();
            $item = ['id' => $id,'name' => $name,'quantity' => $quantity];
            $products[] = $item;
            //print_r($products);
            setcookie('products',json_encode($products),strtotime( '+30 days' ));
            echo 'done';

        }
    }
```

and in the checkout page

```
if(!empty($_COOKIE['products'])){
    $products_in_cart = json_decode($_COOKIE['products'],true);

    foreach($products_in_cart as $product){
        $db->where('id',$product['id']);
        $item = $db->get('products');
        $item[0]['quantity'] = $product['quantity'];
        $products[] = $item;
    }
}
$objSmarty->assign('products',$products);
```

Array- I printed this in the template file using {$products|print_r}:

```
Array
   (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name] => Rug Rat
                    [code] => Part #E13
                    [price] => 59.95
                    [image] => acc2.jpg
                    [catid] => 3
                    [subcatid] => 0
                    [description] =>product One description.
                    [status] => Y
                    [quantity] => 2
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [name] => Mophead Floor Tool 
                    [code] => Part #A52 
                    [price] => 36.95
                    [image] => acc4.jpg
                    [catid] => 3
                    [subcatid] => 0
                    [description] => product two description.
                    [status] => Y
                    [quantity] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

In the template file:

```
{foreach from=$products item='product' name='product'}
{$product[0].price|trim}
    <input type='hidden' class="name" name='item_name_{$smarty.foreach.product.index+1}' value='{$product[0].name|escape}'>
    <input type='hidden' name='amount_{$smarty.foreach.product.index+1}' id="amount" value='{$product[0].price}'>
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity_{$smarty.foreach.product.index+1}" value="{$product[0].quantity|escape}">
{/foreach}
```

Comment: `[object Object]` seems like something Javascript would produce, not PHP. Please provide a minimal test case with values for `$product` that one could reproduce.

Comment: @deceze bro I have updated my question.

Comment: `products` != `product`…!?

Comment: @deceze I dont understand bro

Comment: You `$objSmarty->assign('products')`, you're trying to use `{$product[0].price}`. At the very least there's some *??? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ ???* inbetween there.

Comment: @deceze yes bro. products is an array I am using foreach. I have also updaed my question with more detail